# Google maps and Selenium IDE selection

Tags: google-maps, firefox, selenium, selenium-ide

I'm new in automatic testing and Selenium. I have problem with selection in google maps. I open list with word but couldn't find way to select http://prntscr.com/4elckp . Browser is Firefox.

Comment: This is just testing Google Maps which Google will already do in a more effective manner!

Answer (score 1):

you can try the record button which will record your test case. click on the red button at the top right corner and go to the google maps page and do whatever activity you wanted to do, make sure that no extra activity is recorded, else exclude it.

for example: if you type the minimise button, this too will be recorded so once your test case has been recorded, just remove the extra command on it

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I already tray it , but with no success. It record step when I click on text box to enter word but no record when I click on option